# how to get single value by cookie in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

java script code is store cookie

```
document.cookie = 'CookieName='+'grid';
```

i want to get `CookieName` value `grid` i haveto  store many cookie  but i get this one this cookie store at the first index in cookie

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var CookieName=document.cookie; 
      if(CookieName =='grid')
    { 
   $('#tab_b').hide();
   $('#tab_a').show();
}
else { 
  $('#tab_a').hide(); 
  $('#tab_b').show();
}

});
```

how to get  CookieName value

Comment: Why are you creating the cookie in Javascript and not PHP?

Comment: i'm using tabing of jquery have  grid view and list view on same page  i want to search from grid view and list view and  while searching i 'm on list view only show record in list view and i'm on grid view show record in grid view form have same page

Comment: document.cookie returns all cookie set as string `CookieName=grid;Another=its_value`

Comment: i want to hide tabing div while base on cookie

Comment: only this one i want to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a small function (I could probably make this much more efficient, but I have used it for a long time) which should work for you:

```
function getCookieAttr(attribute) {
    var attr = attribute + "="; // create an attribute string
    var parts = document.cookie.split(';'); // split the cookie into parts
    for(var i = 0; i <parts.length; i++) { // loop through the parts for each item
        var item = parts[i];
        while (item.charAt(0)==' ') { // account for spaces in the cookie
            item = item.substring(1); // set the item
        }
        if (item.indexOf(attr) == 0) { // if the item matches the attribute
            return item.substring(attr.length,item.length); // return the value
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

To use the function pass the attribute name:

```
document.cookie = "CookieName=grid";
console.log(getCookieAttr('CookieName'));
```

Comment: thanks bro  i have got it and  very simple and short function   check it       var allcookies = document.cookie;
                  cookiearray = allcookies.split(';'); 
                  name = cookiearray[0].split('=')[0];
                  value = cookiearray[0].split('=')[1];

Answer (score 1):

I got the impression that you found the answer by Jay Blanchard too long, so I'll provide a shorter alternative. But first let me say something else. As a comment to Jay Blanchard's answer, you wrote:

> thanks bro i have got it and very simple and short function check it `var allcookies = document.cookie; cookiearray = allcookies.split(';'); name = cookiearray[0].split('=')[0]; value = cookiearray[0].split('=')[1];`

However, I highly recommend you rethink that as this assumes `CookieName` is always the first cookie. (Someone might say "but I will somehow make sure it always is", but the point is, this is key/value, not array, so the approach is conceptually wrong and confusing, or as they say, bad practice).

Now, for the code:

```
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)CookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

This is something I have blantantly stolen from [the MDN page on cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Example_2_Get_a_sample_cookie_named_test2) which I highly recommend if you want to learn more about cookies.

Comment: @GhulamAbbas Great, glad I could help! Also, (like Jay Blanchard said in his comment to the question), I recommend you pick an accepted answer(or explain what the current ones are lacking). This will help both you, the people answering, and the community.

Comment: @GhulamAbbas You need to accept this as the answer if it is what solved your issue: just ticke the grey tick under the up and downvoting for the answer. You'll get points and users will be more inclined to give you support in future.